# Copy the first N words in a string in java

Tags: java, string, text, words

I want to select the first N words of a text string.
I have tried `split()` and `substring()` to no avail.
What I want is to select the first 3 words of the following prayer and copy them to another variable.

For example if I have a string:

```
String greeting = "Hello this is just an example"
```

I want to get into the variable Z the first 3 words so that

```
Z = "Hello this is"
```

Comment: Like I said ... eh I tried using split and substring such as:

Comment: while((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
          contenido = contenido + linea;
          String word = contenido.substring(0, 26);
          String rest = contenido.substring(27);

Comment: **1** split string to ' ' => get array ... **2** from array take first n strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String myString = "Copying first N numbers of words to a string";
    String [] arr = myString.split("\\s+"); 
         //Splits words & assign to the arr[]  ex : arr[0] -> Copying ,arr[1] -> first


        int N=3; // NUMBER OF WORDS THAT YOU NEED
        String nWords="";

        // concatenating number of words that you required
        for(int i=0; i<N ; i++){
             nWords = nWords + " " + arr[i] ;         
        }

    System.out.println(nWords);
```

NOTE : Here **.split()** function returns an array of strings computed by splitting a given string around **matches of the given regular expression**

so if i write the code like follows

```
String myString = "1234M567M98723651";
String[] arr = myString.split("M"); //idea : split the words if 'M' presents
```

then answers will be :
 1234 and 567 where stored into an array.

This is doing by storing the split values into the given array. first split value store to arr[0], second goes to arr[1].

Later part of the code is for concatenating the required number of split words

Hope that you can get an idea from this!!!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Omal, could you explain your answer? Usually code-only answers are best avoided because a bit of explanation can really help the asker (and others) to understand *why* you've done what you did

Comment: Thanks for the help.
And finally did this come je.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Wai Ha Lee - really thanks for your request!! I did some explanation there. Hava a nice day!!

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getFirstNStrings(String str, int n) {
    String[] sArr = str.split(" ");
    String firstStrs = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        firstStrs += sArr[i] + " ";
    return firstStrs.trim();
}
```

Now `getFirstNStrings("Hello this is just an example", 3);` will output:

> Hello this is

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
String greeting = "Hello this is just an example";
int end = 0;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    end = greeting.indexOf(' ', end) + 1;
}
String Z = greeting.substring(0, end - 1);
```

N.B. This assumes there are at least three space characters in your source string. Any less and this code will probably fail.

Comment: I tried that but I still throwing the same as with previous attempts. My chain is more or less like "hi hello nice to see u too :) I m or f? M old boy how old? 26 single i am 21 single not old? But"

Comment: This is my code :       while((linea = br.readLine()) != null){
          contenido = contenido + linea;
          int end = 0;
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
    end = contenido.indexOf(' ', end);
}
word = contenido.substring(0, end);
          
       System.out.println(word);

Comment: @ObedHiguera my first draft had some bugs which I've now fixed. Note the "+1" after indexOf() and the "-1" in substring(). That could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in a utility class, such as Util.java

```
public static String getFirstNWords(String s, int n) {
    if (s == null) return null;
    String [] sArr = s.split("\\s+");
    if (n >= sArr.length)
        return s;

    String firstN = "";

    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        firstN += sArr[i] + " ";
    }
    firstN += sArr[n-1];
    return firstN;
}
```

Usage:
Util.getFirstNWords("This will give you the first N words", 3);
---->
"This will give"

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache Commons Lang3, you can make it a little shorter like this:

```
public String firstNWords(String input, int numOfWords) {
    String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
    tokens = ArrayUtils.subarray(tokens, 0, numOfWords);
    return StringUtils.join(tokens, ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers posted already use regular expressions which can become an overhead if we have to process a large number of strings. Even `str.split(" ")` uses regular expression operations internally. dave's answer is perhaps the mos efficient, but it does not handle correctly strings that have multiple spaces occurring together, beside assuming that regular space is the only word separator and that the input string has 3 or more words (an assumption he has already called out). If using Apache Commons in an option, then I would use the following code as it is not only concise and avoids using regular expression even internally but also handled gracefully input strings that have less than 3 words:

```
/* Splits by whitespace characters. All characters after the 3rd whitespace,
 * if present in the input string, go into the 4th "word", which could really
 * be a concanetation of multiple words. For the example in the question, the
 * 4th "word" in the result array would be "just an example". Invoking the
 * utility method with max-splits specified is slightly more efficient as it
 * avoids the need to look for and split by space after the first 3 words have
 * been extracted
 */
String[] words = StringUtils.split(greeting, null, 4);
String Z = StringUtils.join((String[]) ArrayUtils.subarray(words, 0, 3), ' ');
```