# String action 3 first words

Tags: java

Hello I want to do Helping Action that if Have `Sring s = "Good morning everyone today this is Friday"` and I want only the 3 first words `String newS = "Good morning everyone"`

But

if `Sring s = ""; newS = ""`

if `Sring s = "Good"; newS = "Good"`

if `Sring s = "Good morning"; newS = "Good morning"`

thank you very much for helping!

Comment: checkout answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859698/copy-the-first-n-words-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ca do it similar to this:

Split the sentence you want to reduce into an array:

`String[] splitted = s.split("\s+")`

now we have to created a new String which contains only the first three words. And to be fair there are many ways to achieve this.

I would simply use something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < splitted.length;i++)
{
    sb.append(splitted[i]);
    if(i == 2)
    {
        break;
    }   
}
String newS = sb.toString();
```

The only requirement for this implementation to work is that all words are devided by a normal space.

Comment: Thank you very much this is  working. but if(i == 3) replace if(i==2)

Comment: @EranPeer No Problem, in adition if you are uncertain how many spaces lie between the words you can use `s.split("\\s+")`which will ignore the amount of whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you! for your helping

Answer (score 3):

Using java 8:

```
String newS = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).limit(3).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```